# How to install nuxt on cPanel Servers?

Tags: laravel, installation, cpanel, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I have a project written by Laravel and vue.js+nuxt I want to install it on a web server [alsaedco](https://www.alsaedco.com/en/product-category/coffee-shop-equipment-en/)
 I use NUXT for SSR talk but, I don't know it on Cpanel
My question is How to install nuxt on cpanel?

Answer (score -1):

log into your cPanel from SSH and

first install npx

```
npm install -g npx
```

then install nuxt

```
npx create-nuxt-app <project-name>
```

Comment: In systems provider companies
These commands are not allowed on shared hosting.
What is your solution to this?
is there any other way. Or should I buy a VPS